# Encoding error when converting Hex to Base64 Python

Tags: python, encoding

I am currently beginning python, and writing a program that will convert a given long string of hex numbers, that should be separated into pairs. I am having a hard time utilizing pythons encoding function.

So far, I have:

```
import base64

def splitByTwo(str):
    return [i+j for i,j in zip(list(str)[::2], list(str)[1::2])]

def bytesToBase64(str):
    b64List = []
    stringsByTwo = splitByTwo(str.upper())
    for x in stringsByTwo:
        b64List.insert(stringsByTwo.index(x), base64.b16decode(x))
    return b64List

print(bytesToBase64("49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"))
```

I can get it to print `[b'I', b"'", b'm', b'm', b'm', b' ', b' ',.....]` but I am not sure what is wrong with my encode/decode to base64 section of the `bytesToBase64()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bytesToBase64` function returns a list of bytes represented by the given hex string (garbled a little bit because you used `insert` instead of `append`). You haven't done the base64 encoding part.

To fix your existing function:

```
def bytesToBase64(str):
    b64List = []
    stringsByTwo = splitByTwo(str.upper())
    for x in stringsByTwo:
        b64List.append(base64.b16decode(x))
    print base64.b64encode("".join(b64List))
```

But this function is not very idiomatic. To completely rewrite it:

```
def bytesToBase64(s):
    return base64.b64encode(binascii.unhexlify(s))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was having a hard time understanding the functionality of the base64 part, as in how it uses and what it uses as arguments. The documentation was a little hard to understand, but now I get it.